# Does thIs JavaScript syntax exist?

Tags: javascript

I vaguely remember a JavaScript syntax that looks something like this:

```
foo = bar ? {
    condition1 :
    condition2 :
    ...
} [item1, item2, ...]
```

I remember this will assign one of the values in the array to **foo** depending on the code inside of the block ( or something similar ).

Can someone plrase help me with this? Or did I completely imagine this and somehow believed it to be true?

Thanks!

Comment: [Conditional/ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: What is `code`? Statements, part of an object literal, something else?

Comment: It looks like a malformed ternary expression. `var a = b ? true : false;`: if `b` is truthy set `a` to true, otherwise set it to `false`.

Comment: @PeterMader code is what determines which of the array items gets assigned to variable foo, I remembered this to be multiline code, as many lines as the array size

Comment: What is `bar` (or what would you expect to happen to it), and how would these "conditions" look exactly? Would they be values to switch on, or boolean expressions, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You might be talking about this syntax

```
var foo = [item1, item2, item3...][index]; //general syntax
var foo = ["a", "b", "c"][0]; //a
var foo = ["a", "b", "c"][1]; //b
var foo = ["a", "b", "c"][2]; //c
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's called the ternary operator, and works like this.

```
condition ? iftrue : iffalse
```

For example, this:

```
fee = isMember ? '2.50' : '5.00';
alert('Your fee is $' + fee);
```

Is equal to this:

```
if(isMember) {
    fee = '2.50';
} else {
    fee = '5.00';
}
alert('Your fee is $' + fee);
```

---

---

(EDIT) Maybe you can use something like this:

```
foo = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3'][
    condition0 && 0 ||
    condition1 && 1 ||
    condition2 && 2 ||
    condition3 && 3]
```

Comment: Yea functionally this, But I am looking for a super condensed way of writing it all

Comment: I'd say one line is pretty condensed... do you mean you want to use a function instead of `isMember`, and have it based of off what the function returns?

Comment: this can get quite hard to read once you start nesting conditions, the syntax I referred to lists out a condition a line, then after that an array with equal number of valeus, one of which gets chosen depending on which condition returned true.

Comment: I edited the answer with a possible solution. It probably isn't what you were using before but it's short-ish, and one condition per line, only thing is you have to type the index.

Answer (score 0):

No, that certainly doesn't exist. You could do something like this:

```
foo = function (condition, array) {
  if (condition === 'a') {
    return array[0];
  }
  if (condition === 'b') {
    return array[1];
  }
}(bar, [item1, item2, ...]);
```

Working example:

```js
var foo = function (condition, array) {
  if (condition === 'a') {
    return array[0];
  }
  if (condition === 'b') {
    return array[1];
  }
}('b', ['some', 'array', 'containing', 'words']);

console.log(foo);
```

That would do what you wanted, but it seems overly complicated.

Comment: There was definitely an array in there, and there was no **if... else if** or **function** or **return** at all, also I don't remember opening and closing so many curly brackets, it was one line per case. I had it tested and it worked, I was so excited because this would shorten a lot of my code. But now I forgot how to write it, sigh...